# C++: How do I ignore the first directory path when comparing paths in boost::filesystem?

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems, boost-filesystem

I'm trying to compare two directories and find what files are different **inside**.  So I'm using a `boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` to add all contents of each directory to respective vectors.  Then I sort each vector alphabetically and start comparing paths.  The problem is it's including the 'base' path and I don't want that, example:

Version1/Assets/info.txt

Version2/Assets/info.txt

Those paths are comparing different, but I want them to compare the same.  To clarify, I'm not even checking the binaries yet, just the path name so far.  I'd to compare them like this:

/Assets/info.txt

I've been browsing through the boost documentation for a couple hours and I'm convinced there must be an elegant solution for my problem.  I realize I could have solved this a while ago by getting a substring of what I want, but there must be a less ugly way.

Comment: The substring method is probably your best bet.  It's what I do when comparing two directory trees.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` has a `path()` property that you can query. You can then use the following decomposition methods available for `boost::filesystem::path` to manually build the path to compare:

```
path  root_path() const; 
path  root_name() const;         // returns 0 or 1 element path
path  root_directory() const;    // returns 0 or 1 element path
path  relative_path() const;
path  parent_path() const;
path  filename() const;          // returns 0 or 1 element path
path  stem() const;              // returns 0 or 1 element path
path  extension() const;         // returns 0 or 1 element path
```

For example you can rollout a version of stripping the root as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

boost::filesystem::path strip_root(const boost::filesystem::path& p) {
    const boost::filesystem::path& parent_path = p.parent_path();
    if (parent_path.empty() || parent_path.string() == "/")
        return boost::filesystem::path();
    else
        return strip_root(parent_path) / p.filename();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << strip_root("/a") << std::endl;
    std::cout << strip_root("/a/b") << std::endl;
    std::cout << strip_root("/a/b/c") << std::endl;
    std::cout << strip_root("/a/b.dir/c.ext") << std::endl;    
}
// Output:
""
"b"
"b/c"
"b.dir/c.ext"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I have cleaner solution:

```cpp
fs::path stripFirstDir(fs::path p)
{
    p = p.relative_path();
    if (p.empty()) return {};
    return p.lexically_relative(*p.begin());
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hr3hcr